# How can I combine multiple personal geodatabase with same format in Access file?

Tags: merge, esri-geodatabase, table, ms-access

I have multiple geodatabases with the same format in features and attribute tables, their difference is thier location, how I can combine them in one file in Access format which has one attribute table for each feature in Access file?
I want to create one geodatabase from many mdb files which have same format, for example in all of them have same features with same attribute table , how can I create one Access file with them?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify which GIS software you intend to use to merge these Access databases.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few options for this:

1. If you have ArcGIS Desktop you may create a new mdb in Catalog and then use the Merge tool to merge each like name fc from the two mdb and create the new layers in the new mdb (more of a manual process).
2. If you have FME you could setup a simple reader and writer object that merges like name mdb fc and creates them in a new mdb
3. If you have QGIS or gdal ogr2ogr you may use OSGeo4W command terminal to merge both mdb fc together to a new mdb (this will automatically merge like name fc)

Comment: I have hundreds geodatabase with same format, Merge order is cmplicated way through ArcGIS

Comment: I would recommend option 2 or 3 then so you can do it in batch.